# Angular 7 relocate Assets File after Build

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7, angular-cli-v6

I have this `sitemap.xml` file in my `assets` folder under `src`:
[image: assets folder]

When building my project via the cli with `ng build --prod` the resulting folder looks like this:
[image: assets folder]

My question is simply how I can move the `sitemap.xml` file outside the `assets` folder when building my project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the documentation [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration), you just need to update your `angular.json` file.

Something like the following should work for your sitemap file:

```
"assets": [{ "glob": "sitemap.xml", "input": "src/assets/", "output": "/" }],
```